# SQL Server 19 UBUNTU - sporadically crashing and restarting

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I created a machine with 6 GB of memory, using Ubuntu 20, and installed the latest version of SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server:
(RTM-CU8) (KB4577194) - 15.0.4073.23 (X64)
Sep 23 2020 16:03:08
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Exporadically the system suffers a fatal failure and restarts, taking almost a minute to return. I cannot detect the real reason for the failure and what I could do to resolve it.

### I already set the maximum memory limit to 4gb thinking that the system was overflowing the machine's limit. Help me please

> This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running
> at Mon Dec 21 14:31:38 2020 The following diagnostic information is
> available:
> Reason: 0x00000006
> Message: Kernel bug check
> Address: 0x3fff86a3be90
> Parameters: 0xca6e6e240
> Stack Trace:
> file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030E7D9
> file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030C769
> file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000023BEEB
> file:///windows/System32/Drivers/Afd.sys+0x0000000000006385
> file:///windows/System32/Drivers/Afd.sys+0x000000000000686F
> file:///windows/System32/Drivers/Afd.sys+0x000000000000631A
> file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x00000000002412B6
> file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000202FE2
> file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000347898
> file:///Windows/system32/mswsock.dll+0x00000000000015EC
> file:///Windows/SYSTEM32/WS2_32.dll+0x000000000000A6BE
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000003C90B6
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000003C9854
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000000149CD
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x0000000000014DBA
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000001FA73B
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000001FA663
> file:///binn/sqllang.dll+0x00000000001FA0EF
> file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x0000000000009FF3
> file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000000A92D
> file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000000A51E
> file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x00000000000217F2
> file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x000000000002215C
> file:///binn/sqldk.dll+0x0000000000021F53
> file:///Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL+0x0000000000014414
> file:///windows/system32/ntdll.dll+0x0000000000075541
> +0x00000000E7E27000
> Process: 90917 - sqlservr
> Thread: 99182 (application thread 0x2c34)
> Instance Id: 8638650d-adf3-4e7e-8b1b-6cdecd05544c
> Crash Id: 43334ff2-47c7-4fb5-a22e-16f4e0728252
> Build stamp: 98b2cf08cbfec4dc5f2c5d0e2a892c88d339a4da408744f2baf39941a977fa3c
> Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
> Processors: 4    Total Memory: 6234537984 bytes
> Timestamp: Mon Dec 21 14:31:38 2020
> Last errno: 11 Last errno text: Resource temporarily unavailable Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Capturing core dump and information to
> /var/opt/mssql/log...  #033[0;1;39mHint: You are currently not seeing
> messages from other users and the system.#033[0m  #033[0;1;39m
> Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.#033[0m
> #033[0;1;39m      Pass -q to turn off this notice.#033[0m  #033[0;1;31mNo journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.#033[0m  #033[0;1;39mHint: You are currently not seeing
> messages from other users and the system.#033[0m  #033[0;1;39m
> Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.#033[0m
> #033[0;1;39m      Pass -q to turn off this notice.#033[0m  #033[0;1;31mNo journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.#033[0m  /usr/bin/tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for
> reading: Permission denied Mon 21 Dec 2020 02:31:40 PM -03 Capturing
> program information Mon 21 Dec 2020 02:31:42 PM -03 Attempting to
> capture a dump with paldumper for pid 90917

Comment: Considering that Ubuntu 20.04 isn't official supported yet, I would recommend using a supported version (aka 18.04).

Comment: The error already happened in ubuntu 18, in the same way. then I upgraded to 20 to see if there was any difference